# Grails Spring Security verify access for multiple url

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, gsp

I would like to verify if the user has access to more than one url, in a view, like this:

```
<sec:access url="/user,/client">
```

Just like the sec:ifAnyGranted tag for roles:

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERVISOR">
```

In my verifications, the **sec:access url** just works with one url.
Is there any way or alternative to this?

I'm using the spring-security-core:2.0-RC2 plugin for grails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't thing multiple URLs is supported. You can create your own tag to do this like

```
class CustomTagLib {

    static namespace = "myTag"

    def ifAnyGranted = { attrs, body ->
        List<String> urls = attrs.remove('urls').split(',')
        Boolean hasAccess = Boolean.FALSE
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
            hasAccess = sec.access(url: urls.get(i).trim()) { Boolean.TRUE }
            if (hasAccess) {
                out << body()
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it in the view like:

```
<myTag:ifAnyGranted urls="/domain/index,/domain/show">
    Something to display if has access to anyone of the URL
</myTag:ifAnyGranted>
```

Comment: I've thought on doing that, but I couldn't accept there isn't a Spring way to doing it.
Thanks, that's my solution for now.